# socket.io or innerHTML not functioning

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, innerhtml

Aim: To make the bundle sent to server show up in all clients currently connected to the port.

Server-side NodeJS code:

```js
const http = require("http");
const host = 'localhost';
const port = 8000;
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static('./'));
const socketIO = require("socket.io");

// creating the server and starting it on port 8000
app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'))
})
const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port, host, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on http://${host}:${port}`);
});

// making io object
const io = socketIO(server, {cookie: false});   

// listening to connections to the server
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    // chat message coming to server

    socket.on("chatMessage", (chatBundle) => {
        socket.emit("toClient", chatBundle)
    });
});
```

Client-side HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>CHAT ROOM</h1>
        <form onsubmit="return sendServer()">
            <label for="name">Name: 
                <input id="name" name="name" type="text">
            </label>
            
            <label for="text">Message: 
                <input id="text" name="text" type="text">
            </label>
            
            <input type="submit" id="send">
        </form>
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js">
        </script>
        <script>
            const socket = io(); // added
            function sendServer(){
                var sender = document.getElementById("name").value;
                var text = document.getElementById("text").value;
                var tempArray = [sender, text]
                socket.emit("chatMessage", tempArray)
                return false; // added
            };
            socket.on("toClient", (bundleBack) => {
                var tempObject = document.createElement("p")
                tempObject.innerHTML = bundleBack[0] + ": " + bundleBack[1]
            });
        </script>
            
    </body>
</html>
```

Where is the bundle going wrong? Is there a problem with the double nested socket functions in js? Or is it a problem with the innerHTML I'm using in the HTML?

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: I don't know how to debug this

Comment: Use `debugger` or `console.log`. Open console and read the errors first